# ¿Cómo mover una columna de un Grid a la derecha?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Tengo la siguiente duda, quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de mover la columna que se encuentra en la segunda fila hacía la derecha, tome como ejemplo la imagen que aparece en la documentación de bootstrap para luego implementarlo en mi sistema.
[image: Columnas]

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y especifica la version de bootstrap que estas usando ya que en algunas versioens existe la opcion float-left y float right, mientras otras manejan el prefijo de clase float end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo podrías solucionar aplicando la propiedad `justify-content-end`, ya que con esto estarías posicionando el contenido siempre al final, veamos un ejemplo:

```css
.col {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f1e9fe;
  border: 1px #d5c0fc solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row row-cols-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como verás, el bloque se posicionará siempre al final, y si agregamos más bloques, ocurriría lo mismo.

```css
.col {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f1e9fe;
  border: 1px #d5c0fc solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row row-cols-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

También, como algo adicional, si quieres que los bloques estén separados de esquina a esquina, lo harías con `justify-content-between`, por ejemplo:

```css
.col {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f1e9fe;
  border: 1px #d5c0fc solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row row-cols-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Recuerda ver la [**documentación**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) sobre **flex** de Bootstrap para que sepas más sobre esto.

Answer (score 0):

entendería que hay 2 formas:

1. Al 4 item, agregar la clase "offset-2"
2. Al div con la clase row, agregar la clase "justify-content-end"

Tu decide cual aplicar.